# How to change update At-spi1.32 to At-spi2 core in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, python-2.7

On Ubuntu 12.04 by default `At-spi1.32` and `py-atspi 1.9.0` are installed.
I am trying to intstall `atspi2-core` and `pyatspi2` because in there are new methods I need.
When I am trying to import like `from gi.repository import Atspi` it will take take old 'Atspi1.32`.

How to install and set up Atspi2 and pyatspi2 on ubuntu12.04?